# How to implement this activation function in numpy?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, scipy

How can I implement with numpy:

[image]

and its derivative `f'(x)`? I tried to:

```
    def func (x,y):
        if x.all() <= 0:
           y = beta (np.exp(x)-1)
           return y
        elif x>0:
            y = x
            return y
```

However they're not working. Note that `x` and `y` are arrays.

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
def func (x, beta):
    y = np.empty_like(x)
    mask = x <= 0
    y[mask] = beta * (np.exp(x[mask])-1)
    y[~mask] = x[~mask]
   return y
```

mask contains the indizes for elements that are <= 0, so that you can seperate the two cases.

Comment: Better to use `np.expm1` instead of `np.exp(...)-1`, it is designed to compute exp(x)-1 without losing precision when x is close to 0. Compare `np.exp(-1e-20) - 1` and `np.expm1(-1e-20)`.

Comment: can you provide an example?

Comment: Its not working... what about the derivative of the function?

Comment: `f_deriv = lambda x: b*exp(x) if x < 0 else 1 if x > 0 else None`. Something like that. For any `beta != 1` your function is not derivable in 0.